# Convert 10 bit number to mantissa-exponent and vice-versa

Tags: math, binary, mpeg, mpeg2-ts

From: ST 2022-3:2010 - SMPTE Standard https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7290021

How do I understand and do this:

> `Maximum_bit_rate` (**Mode 1 only**): This field shall contain a
> 10-bit number where the first seven bits contain the mantissa value
> and the last 3 bits contain an exponent value defining the multiplier
> of 10 Kbs up to 1,280.0 Gbs.

As far as I understand

> up to 1,280.0 Gbs

means not including that value?

Do I have to divide number by 10000 and represent in binary, so I am storing up to 128,000,000 in binary?

Comment: Do you understand the part about bits?

Comment: this is only information I have. I couldn't understand much on how about I should I go about this

Comment: *This field shall contain a 10-bit number where the first seven bits contain the mantissa value and the last 3 bits contain an exponent value* means that the value is `(7 bit value) * 2^(3 bit exponent)`, or something like that.  With floating point there is an implicit one somewhere but can remember off the top of my head.

Comment: @NathanOliver then max value is just: `127 * 128 = 16256`

Comment: @NathanOliver the base seems to be decimal: `(1280G/2^^7/10K)^^(1/(2^^3)-1)=10`

Comment: @Red.Wave That looks pretty likely.  I used `2` as that is what FP uses but using base 10 gives a max value that is 1,270 Gbs, so that must be it.  Not sure how to get the max of 1,280 Gbs.  I wonder if they have an implicit add of `1` to the value of the mantissa.

Comment: `struct{uint16_t man:7; uint16_t exp:3; operator uint64_t(){return man*pow(10ull,exp);};`

Comment: @Red.Wave sorry but I have trouble understanding `(1280G/2^^7/10K)^^(1/(2^^3)-1)=10`, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess its upto (not including) 1280 Gbs, so max value I think should be equal to 1270 Gbs.

Comment: @nullptr Yeah, up to means does not actually include the value, so 1,270 is probably the max.

Comment: @NathanOliver a bias of 1 is needed. 0 makes no sense.

Comment: `operator uint64_t(){return (1+man)*pow(10ull,exp);};`

Comment: @Red.Wave thanks, yeah, so it should be: `man * pow(10, exp - 1)` with bias `1`, right?

Comment: hate it when this paragraph written in standard document without any further single piece of detail :(

Comment: Please don't tag irrelevant languages, if this is an excerpt from a standard providing the standard would help people give the correct answer rather than guessing in the comments

Comment: @AlanBirtles updated question to provide link to standard document

Comment: @nullptr No. `operator uint64_t(){return (1ull+man)*pow(10ull,exp);};` the bias belongs to mantis. Also note the type of literal values, or overflow will lead to bugs.

Comment: up to can include the value or not, depending.

Comment: To make matters worse, the standard document is not available for free... The definition is ambiguous.

Comment: You almost certainly want to ask the folks who published that spec. And then when you get the answer, you can post that here and accept it for future reference.

Comment: My guess from what you've said is that it's Kbsresult = 10Kbs*((x+1) * 10^y) where x is the first 7 bits and y is the last 3 bits, but 0 to 6 as 7 is not required or can be used for NAN etc.

Answer (score 0):

The specification is unclear:

- it does not specify if the 7 bit mantissa includes all significant bits or if there is an implied initial `1` as is the case for IEEE 32-bit and 64-bit floating point representations,
- the *3 bit exponent value* is probably not a shift count, it could be a power of 10 or more likely an index in a table of multipliers as the phrase *defining the multiplier of 10 Kbs up to 1,280.0 Gbs* indicates.

The document in reference is not available for free so there is no access to further information available to try and construct a function to convert these 10-bit values to an actual number.

Comment: Well yeah, the specification is vague. The second similar field is:
*Maximum_latency (Mode 1 only): This field shall contain a 10-bit number defining the multiplier of 10 ms equal to the maximum FEC latency up to 10.24 seconds*

Comment: Nothing else explained about these fields, i.e. maximum_bitrate of what? Media streams or fec streams?

Comment: @nullptr: in the case of *Maximum_latency*, the field seems to be just an integer with a range of `0` to `1023` for a number of units of 10ms and they should have written **10.23** seconds.